# Endless loop in a text generation script

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk, markov-chains, language-model

I am trying to make a simple text generator using the Bulgarian language but my code is stuck in an endless loop. Here is the code:

```
from tokenization import tokenize_bulgarian_text
from nltk import bigrams, trigrams
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
import random

with open('IvanVazov1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = f.read()

# Tokenize text
tokenized_sentences = tokenize_bulgarian_text(data)
print(tokenized_sentences)

# Create a placeholder for model
model = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: 0))

# Count frequency of co-occurance  
for sentence in tokenized_sentences:
    for w1, w2, w3 in trigrams(sentence, pad_right=True, pad_left=True):
        print("Trigram:", (w1, w2, w3))
        model[(w1, w2)][w3] += 1
 
# Transform the counts to probabilities
for w1_w2 in model:
    total_count = float(sum(model[w1_w2].values()))
    for w3 in model[w1_w2]:
        model[w1_w2][w3] /= total_count
print(model)


# starting words
text = ["беше"]
sentence_finished = False
 
print("Starting words:", text)

while not sentence_finished:
    # select a random probability threshold  
    r = random.random()
    accumulator = .0
    for word in model[tuple(text[-2:])].keys():
        **# print statement never executes**
        print(f"word: {word}, probability: {model[tuple(text[-2:])][word]}, accumulator: {accumulator}")
        accumulator += model[tuple(text[-2:])][word]
        # select words that are above the probability threshold
        if accumulator >= r:
            text.append(word)
            break

    if text[-2:] == [None, None]:
        print("End of sentence.")
        sentence_finished = True
 
print (' '.join([t for t in text if t]))
```

Here is my tokenization.py file that I import:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
import string
from spacy.lang.bg.stop_words import STOP_WORDS as bg_stopwords


def tokenize_bulgarian_text(text):
    extra_stopwords = {"—", "“", "„", "не", "та", "па"}
    bg_stopwords.update(extra_stopwords)
    # Remove punctuation and lowercase all letters
    text = text.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
    text = text.lower()
    
    # Split the text into individual sentences
    sentences = sent_tokenize(text)

    # Tokenize and filter each sentence
    filtered_tokens = []
    for sentence in sentences:
        # Split the sentence into individual words or tokens
        tokens = word_tokenize(sentence)
        # Remove any stop words from the tokenized text
        filtered_sentence = [word for word in tokens if word not in bg_stopwords]
        filtered_tokens.append(filtered_sentence)

    return filtered_tokens
```

Also the text file I use for data:

```
Нощта беше влажна и мрачна и браилските улици пустееха. Студената декемврийска мъгла, която обикновено пада покрай бреговете на Дунава, се беше напластила в една от главните улици на града и задушаваше с отровния си дъх последните минувачи, които бързаха да се приберат у дома си.
```

From what I have gathered I think the tokenization is fine and the triagrams are correct. I tried using print sentences to debug the code. For some reason the print statement in the nested **for loop** never executes. New words are never appended to the text list. I copy pasted the code from a website and it works fine with `reuters.sents()` instead of my `tokenized_sentences`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please make sure to take the [tour] and learn [ask]. Try to reduce your problem and code sample to a [mcve], and put breaskpoints in your code so you know up to which point your code is reaching.

Comment: We don't provide debugging services. The following references give advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)